# "Eager" loading AngularJS app

Tags: ajax, wordpress, angularjs, loading

I'm working on a new website which can be found under construction here: http://srgunltd.co.uk

I'm pulling data from the WordPress JSON API but if you notice when loading some pages there is a not insignificant delay between the page appearing, and the content appearing (1+ second usually). I could live with this if it wasn't AJAX driven, because this highlights the problem more.

So to avoid ambiguity, my question - are there any plugins or practices for AngularJS which allows "eager" loading of content, so it is readily available *before* page load?

Comment: I feel like a service as a smart cache might be the best practice. This functionality seems to specific for angular to have a solution. Since the flow of your app is totally specific, there's no way for a framework to know what and what not to load eagerly.

Comment: Reading about caching now, can you provide any useful links or examples?

Comment: Switching to answer below..

Comment: if my answer was satisfactory please consider marking answer

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure there is necessarily an "angular" solution to this problem. I think this would fall under the application architecture umbrella. My first thoughts is that you would use a service and implement a caching system that is specific to your needs. Note: there could be cool libraries to help with this sort of thing, but I prefer custom solutions tailored to my needs.

I would do something like this maybe, but again, this is an application specific thing:

```
function dataCacheService($http){

  var dataCache {};
  return {
    // hooks to load data ahead of time
    getPage1 : function(){
      var data = "Data from Api";
      dataCache['page1'] = data;
    },
    getPage2 : function(){
      var data = "Data from Api";
      dataCache['page2'] = data;
    },
    // a check to see if cached data is available
    getCache = function(key){
      return dataCache[key] || false;
    }
  }

}
```

And then when your controller loads you can just call `dataCacheService.getPage1()` to preload the data. When your user goes to the page that requires that data, you can check to see if it exists `dataCacheService.getCache('page1')` or load as normal.

```
function page1Ctrl($scope,$http,dataCacheService){

  // check to see if the data is cached or go get it
  $scope.data = dataCacheService.getCache('page1') || getTheData();

  function getTheData(){
    //get it normally or whatever you need to do
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want an angular solution you can use this angular module:
http://chieffancypants.github.io/angular-loading-bar/

but I think you have to change your code to become all angular oriented, so your loading-bar module must be associated to a controller written in angular code.

I hope this helps you.